# ag-grid: Issue with row grouping with server side row model (ag-grid version 22.1.0)

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid enterprise v22.1.0 and need help with the following:

- I am using default infinite scroll mode for the ag-grid.
- I need to group the rows if ONLY IF there's more than one row.
- We are using `[rowModelType]="'serverSide'"` and it's observed that no matter what, ag-grid always creates a group. It seems like that's the default behaviour for server side row model - it always shows the rows in groups and as the server keeps returning the data, it adds rows to the group.
- The behaviour I am expecting is possible with `[rowModelType]="'clientSide'"`. The row group is not created if there's a single row for the column being grouped.

Is it possible by any way to change this? I would like that the row group is not shown if there's a single record and only convert to group for more than 1 records.

I have checked the [documentation for v22.1.0](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/22.1.0/javascript-grid-server-side-model-grouping/), but can't find a way. Any pointers are appreciated.